# How to toggle switch between celcius and fahrenheit in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

In React.js weather project I want to toggle switch between celcius and fahrenheit.From parent file I get the value of Celcius for 'M' and Fahrenheit for 'I' according to units in weather api.On toggle the value must be changed from Celcius to Fahrenheit and vice-versa.Below is the code for reference

1. App.js (Parent File)

```
class App extends React.Component  { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      lat: '',
      lon: '',
      city: '',
      country: '',
      humidity: '',
      wind: '',
      description: '',
      maxTemp: '',
      minTemp: '',
      precip: '',
      pressure: '',
      hourlyforecast: '',
      error: '',
      sunrise: '',
      sunset: '',
      temp: '',
      unit: {
        M: 'M',
        I: 'I'
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {

    // Here the state of units which is to be used later in api
    // according to toggle switch
    const unitType = (this.state.unit === 'M') ? 'M' : 'I';
    console.log('UNIT', unitType)

      // Tracking the location and 
      // Setting the state of latitude and longitude values
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
        this.setState({
          lat:  position.coords.latitude.toFixed(3),
          lon: position.coords.longitude.toFixed(3)
        }, () => {
          var lat = `${this.state.lat}`;
          var lon = `${this.state.lon}`;

  fetch(`${CURRENT_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
      console.log('DATA CURRENT', responseJson)
    this.setState({
    city: responseJson.data[0].city_name,
    country: responseJson.data[0].country_code,
    temp: responseJson.data[0].temp,
    wind: responseJson.data[0].wind_spd,
    humidity: responseJson.data[0].rh,
    pressure: responseJson.data[0].pres,
    description: responseJson.data[0].weather.description,
    isLoading: false, 
    }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('weather', JSON.stringify(this.state))
    })
    } catch {
      toast.error('Error Code 429')
    }
    console.log('STATE', this.state)

  });

  // Forecast Weather - Daily
  fetch(`${FORECAST_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${unitType}&days=6&key=${API_KEY3}`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
      console.log('DATA I GET', responseJson)
      this.setState({ 
      forecastdays: responseJson.data,
      precip: responseJson.data[0].pop,
      maxTemp: responseJson.data[0].app_max_temp,
      minTemp: responseJson.data[0].app_min_temp,
      sunrise: responseJson.data[0].sunrise_ts,
      sunset: responseJson.data[0].sunset_ts,
      isLoading: false 
      } , () => {
        localStorage.setItem('weather', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      })
    } catch {
      toast.error('Too many requests')
    }

    console.log('STATE I GET', this.state)

  });


// Forecast Weather - Hourly
fetch(`${HOURLY_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}&hours=10`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
      this.setState({
        hourlyforecast: responseJson.data,
        isLoading: false
      }, () => {
        localStorage.setItem('weather', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      })

    } catch {
      toast.error('Please wait some time')
    }

  });
        })
        // Data auto-refreshed every 2 seconds

      },
      (error) => {
        toast.error(`${error.message}`,{
          autoClose: 3000
        })
      // toast.error(`ERROR(${error.code}): ${error.message}` )
    },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 50000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      })   
}

render() {
    const {isLoading, forecastdays, hourlyforecast, precip} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container" style={{marginTop: '3.5em'}}>
        <div className="row">
          {isLoading ? <Spinner/>:  

          <React.Fragment>
          <div className="col-sm-8 image-container">
          {/* Weather Card */}
          <div className="background">
          <div className="container"> 
          <div id="card" className="weather" style={sectionStyle}></div>    
          <div id="card" className="weather2" style={{background: ''}}>

                  <div className="details">
                      {/* Weather Details */}
                       <div className="content" style={{width: '125px'}}>
                       </div>

                      {/* Forecast Cards */}

                      <div className="content" style={{width: '360px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>

                             <div style={{display: 'table', width: '300px'}}>
                        // Celcius to Fahrenheit Toggle Button
                                <CeltoFahr 
                                  style={{display: 'table-cell'}}
                                  unit={this.state.unit}
                                />
                              </div>   
                       </div>
                      {/* Forecast Cards Ends*/  }          
                  </div> 
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          {/* Weather Card Ends */}
          </React.Fragment>    
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

2. CelToFahr.js (Toggle Switch Button)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CountUp from 'react-countup';
import './CelToFahr.css';

class CeltoFahr extends Component {
    state = {
        celOn: true
    }

    switchCel = () => {
        this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn });

       //Here below in console.log I get the 'M' and 'I' both units
       //but, I want to set the state of 'M' when celOn is true
       // and 'I' when its false
        console.log('STATE', this.props.unit)
      };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {/* Code for celcius to farenheit */}
            <div className="weather" style={{margin: '-7em 0em 0em 11em'}}>
                <div className="figures" >
                    <div className="figuresWrap2">
                            <div style={{margin: '5em 0 0em 6em'}} 
                                onClick={this.switchCel} className="CelSwitchWrap">
                                <div className={"CelSwitch" + (this.state.celOn ? "" : " transition")}>
                                    <h3>°C</h3>
                                    <h3>°F</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                {/*End of Code for celcius to farenheit */}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default CeltoFahr
```

As you can see in the comments in switchSel() method. How to toggle between M and I based on user click and trigger it in Parent component i.e App.js file or is there any other logic? Any new method or suggestion highly appreciated... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this `:
{this.state.celOn ? <h3>{this.props.unit.M} °C</h3> : <h3>{this.props.unit.I} °F</h3>}`

In App.js Use This

```
switchCel = () => {
    this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn });
};


<CeltoFahr 
   style={{display: 'table-cell'}}
   unit={this.state.unit}
   toggleBtn={this.switchCel}
/>
```

Comment: How to implement it?

Comment: Take my code and replace with `<div className={"CelSwitch" + (this.state.celOn ? "" : " transition")}>
                                    <h3>°C</h3>
                                    <h3>°F</h3>
                                </div>`

Comment: I'am getting it in the same component, but, the question how to trigger it in App.js component and update the state there?

Comment: put switchCel in App.js and pass it as a props. Or if you must put it inside CelToFahr then create another function inside app.js and pass that as props. When you setState in CelToFahr, then call the props function in the call back.

Comment: I have updated the code. You can check that. Hope it helped. Sorry for the late response...

Answer (score 1):

add a unit to your state

```
state = {
    celOn: true,
    unit: this.props.unit.I
};
```

Change your switch cel to this so it work

```
switchCel = () => {
    const { M, I } = this.props.unit;
    this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn, unit: this.state.celOn ? M : I });
};
```

Then you can load it in DOM using `<h3>{thi.state.unit}C</h3>`